# Ionic 2 - How to disable a button component

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3, angular-components

I have an ionic component which consists of a button that should be disabled if an attribute is true. However, I couldn't figure out how it would work. How could I make it work?

component.html

```
<btn-rounded>
  <button class="ripple" [attr.disabled]="disabled">
    <div>
      {{text | translate}}
    </div>
  </button>
</btn-rounded>
```

component.ts

```
  @Input('text') text: string;
  @Input('disabled') disabled: boolean;

  constructor() {}
```

index.html

```
  <btn-rounded text="Login" [disabled]="!this.login.valid"></btn-rounded>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **[disabled]**

```
 <btn-rounded>
      <button class="ripple" [disabled]="disabled">
        <div>
          {{text | translate}}
        </div>
      </button>
    </btn-rounded>
```

otherwise you can try like this

```
[attr.disabled]="disabled== true ? true : null"
```

Comment: Actually, this is how I tried it first but it didn't work as expected :(

Comment: this not working " <button class="ripple" [disabled]="disabled">"

Comment: I replaced [attr.disabled] to [disabled] and it worked... only in a form login. However, there are terms and conditions to be accepted on a certain page, and now, even if it's clearly disabled, I still can click on and execute its function. Still not working as expected

Comment: weird !! can you create plunker ?

Comment: It was a conflict between `disabled` and `ngClick` which was solved using [this](https://baudehlo.com/2014/02/24/angular-js-ng-click-still-fires-when-div-is-ngdisabled/)